# Changing Checkbox Outline-color with JQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, css

I have a group of checkboxes all with the same name. When using JQuery validate to verify at least one is checked only the first checkbox is set to a red outline and the background set to red. That seems to be done by the validate plugin because with no additional code that still changes.

I have tried the following code and inspect element shows the change to the style of the other checkboxes but they do not change.

```
 <label class="checkbox ">
   <input class="taskcheck" type="checkbox" name="task" value="x">
 </label>

 style="outline-color: rgb(185, 44, 40);"

 errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
      if (element.attr('name') == 'task'){
           $('.taskcheck').css('outline-color','#B92C28');  
      } else {
           error.insertAfter(element.parent());
      }
```

Comment: did you set outline-border ? your bits of code is not enough here to show your issue.

Comment: Just tried that and it did not change the result

Comment: There isn't enough here to help but I tend to agree with @G-Cyr you need to define an outline border and outline style before you can set a color and expect it to be visible.

Comment: How does JQuery validate know to outline the first checkbox in red and change the background to red with the checkboxes all having the same attributes set? The checkboxes all have a name and class with no special settings for border or background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired effect, which was to change all the checkboxes in a group to red when a user try to submit the form. I accomplished this by using in the following in the jquery validate errorPlacement function.

```
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            if (element.attr('name') == 'task'){
                $('ul.task-list').find('label.checkbox').addClass('state-error');
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }
        }
```